# JavaFx circle with two colors

Tags: javafx, colors, geometry

Could someone help me? I Need draw a circle in javaFX. It should be Partially filled (bottom part). Top part should be  transparent. Level of filled part I should able to change in runtime. Also, it could be circle filled with two colors

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a rectangle and a circle as its clipping shape. By moving the rectangle up and down while keeping the clipping in place you could simulate the filling level.

Comment: Good idea. But how can I put rectangle into circle?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **Linear Gradient** to do this inside a method where you must each time indicate a color :

```
private void changeColor(String color){

    if(color == null){
        color = "transparent";
    }

    circle.setStyle("-fx-fill:linear-gradient( from 100.0% 100.0% to 100.0%  0.0%, rgb(77,102,204) 0.5," + color +" 0.5);");

}
```

Here's a demo :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Launcher extends Application{

private Pane root = new Pane();
private Scene scene;
private Circle circle = new Circle(200, 200, 100);
private Button btn = new Button("Change");

private boolean change = false;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {




    btn.setOnAction(evt->{

        if(change){
        change = !change;
        changeColor("red");
        }else{
        change = !change;
        changeColor("transparent");
        }

    });

    changeColor("green");

    root.getChildren().addAll(btn,circle);
    scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}


private void changeColor(String color){

    if(color == null || color.isEmpty()){
        color = "transparent";
    }

    circle.setStyle("-fx-fill:linear-gradient( from 100.0% 100.0% to 100.0% 0.0%, rgb(77,102,204) 0.5," + color +" 0.5);");

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args); 

}

}
```

It's just a simple method you can find better and more powerful example I think, good luck !